# If I destroy a computer, will it lose its programs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

If I destroy my [computer](http://www.computercraft.info/wiki/Computer), will the programs on it remain if I replace it somewhere else?

Comment: I almost flagged this as nonsense, then I saw the game tags. Sneaky...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will lose its programs. A CC computer considers itself "new" when it's placed and will have a new computer ID. (CC stores filesystem contents by computer ID, so having its ID change makes it "lose" its files, even though they're still in your world's save folder if you go looking in Windows Explorer or equivalent.)

However, there's an easy fix. Any computer (including turtles) that has a *label* keep their computer ID and therefore remember their contents. You can set the label with the command:

> label set namegoeshere

Computers forgetting their programs had been giving me a lot of headaches until I learned about labels, since I was using a turtle and a custom tunnel program. Now I have two turtles, Cricket and Grasshopper, and they keep their custom programs when I break and move them. I set their labels with:

> label set cricket

and

> label set grasshopper

No more carrying around floppies and disk drives in the mines!

Answer (score 2):

You can recover lost data if it's your own world (not server).

Method 1. If you know id of destroyed computer, just change number in file ".minecraft/saves//computer/lastid.txt" to id-1. For example, if you want recover computer #5, you must write 4 into this file. If you don't know id, you can search your files in "computer" directory, name of subdirectory is id. After modyfing "lastid.txt" place new computer into the world. Don't forget to restore lastid after this.

Method 2. If you don'n use id in your programs (don't send rednet messages to it etc.) you can place new computer, get its id by "id" command, then get id of lost computer (read method 1) and copy your files from lost computer directory to new one.

Comment: You can also just look through the folder full of computers by ID and find the programs that are in "lost" computers, then copy them wherever you want.

Comment: What are "lost" computers?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing official, just a couple of facts found online:

> Destroying a computer will wipe out any saved programs on that computer. [Source](http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Computer).
>   Labelled computers do keep their data when destroyed. [Source](http://www.computercraft.info/2012/07/29/computercraft-1-41-bugfix-update/).

Answer (score 0):

## NO

Destroying any computers will not wipe out ANY data that it had. Every single program you had on it will still be saved in your world directory. If you want to recover them you can go into `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves/(worldname)/computer/(computerid)/`, its the same for disks: `%appdata%/.minecraft/saves/(worldname)/computer/disk/(diskid)/`.

---

If you do not know how to find the computers id, then you can run `id` in the shell, or if you want to create a program that does it you can do `print(os.getComputerId)`

### NOTE

If you are using mac the locations would be:
Computer:

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/(world)/computer/(computerid)/
```

Disk:

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/(world)/computer/disk/(diskid)/
```

If you are using a server:

```
(SERVER FILES)/(world)/computer/...
```

### EDIT AND CREATE PROGRAMS USING TEXT EDITOR

That is a 100% possible, I also use notepad++ for creating programs, just simply locate the file directory. Also you can create folders and files as you want. BE SURE to **NOT** use any extensions if you are CREATING programs with the editor!

I really hope that this information helped you!